# Compare floating point numbers using regex in Bash

Tags: bash, glob

I need to check if current NTP offset is biger than 2.xxxxx , where xxx is any number
for example 2.005596757,2.006086349

```
offset=$(ntpdate -q 1.2.3.4 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 6 | sed "s/.$//")
echo $offset
```

current offset variable is: 0.841816 so need to compare if X.XXXXXX is bigger or equal to 2.XXXXXXXXX , where X is any number in range [0-9]

```
offset=$(ntpdate -q 10.160.82.10 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 6 | sed "s/.$//")

        
     if [ $offset -ge ([2]+\.?[0-9]*) ]
      then
       echo "offset too high"
     fi
```

But getting error

```
./1.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./1.sh: line 9: `if [ $offset -ge ([2]+\.?[0-9]*)|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+) ]'
```

Comment: You regex is invalid for bash syntax. You can see that on shellcheck.com . Also, for numbers, you are better off using bash's arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you compare only the integer part? Like:

```
if [ ${offset%.*} -ge 2 ]; then
  echo offset too high
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

For comparing a floating point number it is better to use `awk` or `perl` as `bash` can only handle integer numbers.

You may consider this `awk` solution that eliminates `head`, `cut` and `sed` as a bonus:

```bash
if ntpdate -q 1.2.3.4 | awk 'NR == 1 && $6 < 2 {exit 1} {exit 0}'; then
   echo 'offset too high'
fi
```